# Elasticsearch multi node cluster using kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am trying to create a multiple node cluster of elasticsearch. So which service should i use to create a cluster using kubernetes. I was able to do it within a node using headless service for the internal communication between es. But the same is not happening in the case of multiple node. Also which ip and port i have to mention in "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts" of the master node in the elasticsearch.yml file in worker node.

deployment.yml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: elasticsearch-deployment
spec:
 selector:
 matchLabels:
   app: elasticsearch
 replicas: 2
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: elasticsearch
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: elasticsearch
       image: sandeepp163/elasticsearch:latest
       volumeMounts:
       - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/
         name: config
       - mountPath: /var/logs/elasticsearch/
         name: logs
     volumes:
     - name: config
       hostPath:
         path: "/etc/elasticsearch/"
     - name: logs
       hostPath:
         path: "/var/logs/elasticsearch"
```

internal-communication service config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-cluster
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - name: transport
    port: 9300
    targetPort: 9300
```

external service config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: load-service
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31234
    port: 9200
    targetPort: 9200
```

The error im getting on the worker node.

```
[2020-02-26T05:29:02,297][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [worker] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
```

elasticsearch.yml file in worker

```
cluster.name: xxx
node.name: worker
node.master: false
node.data: true
node.ingest: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.9.0"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

elasticsearch.yml in master

```
cluster.name: xxx
node.name: master
node.master: true
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add  elasticsearch version, cluster version, the pod's log that is failing, etc? It will help us understanding your situation better.

Comment: elasticsearch version: Version: 6.1.2, Build: 5b1fea5/2018-01-10T02:35:59.208Z, JVM: 1.8.0_201
logs :- [2020-02-26T05:28:19,634][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [worker] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again

Comment: Can you add the yamls and the configuration files too? please add them in the question body.

Comment: Can you please take a look now.

Comment: "not enough master nodes discovered during pinging" it looks like your master is down.
Is your k8s self hosted?

if you are interested to learn helm, then it is very easy to deploy elastic search clusters using helm charts.
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

You could simply deploy Elasticsearch in a statefulset using HELM.

**1. Installing HELM:**

If you are using linux, type: `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3 | bash`

If not, see [here](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/) the installation process for your O.S.

**2.  Add the stable repository to Helm, and upgrade them:**

```
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

helm repo update
```

**3. Install Elasticsearch Helm chart**

Now you're able to install the [Elasticsearch chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch), type:

```
helm install stable/elasticsearch --generate-name
```

Wait for the installation, you could check using `kubectl get pods -l app=elasticsearch`

To access you could use `proxy-port` on service name:

```
ES_SVC=$(kubectl get svc -owide -l "app=elasticsearch" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")

kubectl port-forward svc/$ES_SVC 9200:9200
```

**4.  Access the service:**

To access the service go to http://127.0.0.1:9200 from your browser.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am asking about multiple node clustering of elasticsearch.

Comment: Yes, i have this stack deploy in a cluster with 3 nodes, helm will manage the statefulset based on all your nodes.

Comment: okay thanks for the info i will try and let you know. Since i haven't started using helm.

Comment: Great, is pretty easy to use, if you try the steps above and see something weird please share and I will try to help you.

Comment: @Mr.KoopaKiller I wonder if you could help me out with a similar issue using HELM to [install elasticsearch with 3 nodes and production certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70305348/11194047)